# Insert Multiple Rows from Table A to Table B on Multiple Different Dates MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, domo

I have Table A with a list of dates

| DATE |
| --- |
| Aug 20, 2021 |
| Aug 21, 2021 |
| Aug 22, 2021 |

And Table B with Variables

| LOCATION | VARIABLE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 200 |

How would I insert both the locations and variables for each date like this?:

| Date | LOCATION | VARIABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aug 20, 2021 | A | 100 |
| Aug 20, 2021 | B | 200 |
| Aug 21, 2021 | A | 100 |
| Aug 21, 2021 | B | 200 |
| Aug 22, 2021 | A | 100 |
| Aug 22, 2021 | B | 200 |

Table A is updated Daily while Table B is Static,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cross join:

```sql
SELECT a.DATE, b.LOCATION, b.VARIABLE
FROM TableA a
CROSS JOIN TableB b;
```

If you actually want to *insert* this data into another table, then use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, using the above select query.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
INSERT INTO <*your table name*> (Date, Location, Variable)
SELECT A.DATE, B.LOCATION, B.VARIABLE
FROM TableA A, TableB B;
```